# Vcenter + can we update memory online in spite Hot-add feature is disabled ,

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Hot-add feature is disable in the vcenter therefore we need to shutdown the Linux OS in order to update the memory.

Since we cant shutdown the linux machine, and we must increase the memory of the linux VM machine, we want to know if there are maybe workarounds where we can update the memory online withou shutting down the machines.

Is it possible?

links - https://www.altaro.com/vmware/vmware-hot-add/

Comment: 'since we cant shutdown the linux machine' - why not? Just shutdown the VCSA, attach directly to the host that owns it, upgrade the memory, restart it - it's that simple.

Comment: Do you want to increase the memory of vcenter itself, or a linux vm that is running on a  vcenter managed host?

Comment: we want to increase the memory of the linux OS itself , but for now we not allowed to shutdown the linux , so we need to add memory online

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in your situation.
Enabling hot-add functionality has to be done while the VM is off.

You really need to take the downtime hit and right-size your Linux virtual machine's memory.

In general, I don't utilize memory and CPU hot-add in VMware because there's a small bit of overhead and it discourages better planning.

See [this discussion](http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2012/01/16/enabling-hot-add-by-default-cc-gabvirtualworld/) for other pros/cons, though.

Comment: on redhat 7 when this hot-add is enabled we can update the memory online without problem for example we can increase the mem from 64G to 128G and it will be immediately effected on the OS

Comment: > In general, I don't utilize memory and CPU hot-add in VMware because there's a
> small bit of overhead and it discourages better planning.
In my experience, it's the other way round... we always enable hot-add for CPU and RAM and tell people to start with small VMs. If they need more CPUs or RAM we *can* do it on the fly... otherwise, people tend to plan for worst case scenarios in order to avoid downtime and order morde ressources than they actually need.